# Retrieving one to many associated data with specific criteria, in a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Using **Postgres 9.6+**, suppose I have a simple **survey model** with three tables: `questions`, `users`, and `answers`. Each answer refers to a question and contains text written by a user.

Here's a simplified example:

```
             questions
|----|------------------------------|
| id | text                         |
|----|------------------------------|
|  1 | Do you like apples?          |
|  2 | What is your favorite color? |
|  3 | How are you feeling today?   |
-------------------------------------

    users
|----|-------|
| id | name  |
|----|-------|
|  1 | Alice |
|  2 | Bob   |
--------------

                answers
|----|---------|-------------|---------|
| id | user_id | question_id | text    |
|----|---------------------------------|
|  1 | 1       | 1           | Yes     |
|  2 | 2       | 1           | No      |
|  3 | 1       | 2           | Yellow  |
|  4 | 2       | 2           | Blue    |
|  5 | 1       | 3           | Good    |
|  6 | 2       | 3           | Fine    |
----------------------------------------
```

My end goal is to be able to feed this into an app that will render a datatable in which each row contains a single user's info alongside their answers to **a dynamic set of questions**. In other words, it might want to retrieve users' answers for questions 1 and 3 specifically:

```
|----|-------|---------------------|----------------------------|
| id | name  | Do you like apples? | How are you feeling today? |
|----|-------|---------------------|----------------------------|
|  1 | Alice | Yes                 | Good                       |
|  2 | Bob   | No                  | Fine                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or any arbitrary combination of questions. Realistically these lists of question_ids might be capped at 10 items or so.

At first, I naively tried to dynamically construct the query JOINing on `answers` once for each question:

```sql
SELECT
  u.name name, 
  a1.text q1, 
  a2.text q2
FROM
  users u
JOIN answers a1 
  ON a1.user_id = u.id AND question_id = 1
JOIN answers a2 
  ON a1.user_id = u.id AND question_id = 3
```

But as the number of JOINs grows, more nested loops seem to be made and performance started taking an increasingly high hit.

An alternative that came up was to try a subquery...

```sql
SELECT
  u.name name, 
  sub.qid question_id,
  sub.text text
FROM
  users u
JOIN (
  SELECT
    a.user_id uid,
    a.question_id qid,
    a.text text
  FROM
    answers a
  WHERE
    a.question_id IN (1, 3)
  GROUP BY
    a.user_id
) sub ON sub.uid = u.id
```

...but since this produces **one row for each answer** instead of for each **user**, I ended up resorting to tricks such as aggregating the answers in a JSONB object to keep the format as desired, replacing the subquery with:

```sql
  SELECT
    a.user_id uid,
    jsonb_object_agg(a.question_id, a.text) question_answers
  FROM
    answers a
  WHERE
    a.question_id IN (1, 3)
  GROUP BY
    a.user_id
```

Which works alright for retrieving the whole dataset, but becomes a pain when retrieving ranges for datatable specific operations... In particular pagination and/or sorting by one of the answers' columns (e.g. sort results by answers of "How are you feeling today?" in descending order).

I feel like I might be missing something here or falling into an antipattern, so I decided to reach for help.

What's the best / most sane way to achieve this kind of result? Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: The aggregation into a JSONB object seems your best option. You can still use it to sort: `select * from ( your query here ) t order by questions_answers ->> 'Do you like apples?'`

Comment: @MikeOrganek @a_horse_with_no_name I experimented with both the `crosstab` function and the JSONB sorting notation - both worked flawlessly and run times were reasonable and very similar! 

In particular I wasn't expecting the JSONB route to be able to leverage indices as well as it did. Super cool.

Thanks to both! I'd upvote but my newbie reputation still forbids me.

Answer (score 0):

I create an example for your question. I used `PIVOT` for better performance.

```
CREATE TABLE #questions  (
  id   int,
  [text]  VARCHAR(100),
);
CREATE TABLE #users  (
  id   int,
  [name]  VARCHAR(100),
);

CREATE TABLE #answers  (
  id   int,
  user_id int,
  question_id int,
  [text]  VARCHAR(100),
);

INSERT INTO #questions
  (id, [text])
VALUES
  (1,'Do you like apples?'),
  (2,'What is your favorite color?'),
  (3,'How are you feeling today?')
  ;
  INSERT INTO #users
  (id, [name])
VALUES
  (1,'Alice'),
  (2,'Bob')
  ;
  INSERT INTO #answers
  (id,user_id,question_id, [text])
VALUES
  (1,1,1,'Yes'),
  (2,2,1,'No'),
  (3,1,2,'Yellow'),
  (4,2,2,'Blue'),
  (5,1,3,'Good'),
  (6,2,3,'Fine')
  ;

   declare @questions VARCHAR(100)
 ;with CTE_question as (select text ttext from #questions)

 select @questions=STRING_AGG(+'['+ttext +']',',') from CTE_question

 

 execute('SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        u.name [Name], 
        q.text [Question],
        a.text [Answer]
    FROM 
        #questions q 
                 join #answers a on q.id = a.question_id
                 join #users u on a.user_id=u.id
                 
) t 
PIVOT(
    max([Answer]) 
    FOR [Question] IN (
      '+  @questions+'
        )
) AS pivot_table
')
```

result =

```
Name    Do you like apples?   What is your favorite color?  How are you feeling today?
Alice     Yes                   Yellow                               Good
 Bob      No                     Blue                                 Fine
```

Comment: I had no prior experience with pivot tables so it was a bit hard to grasp what's going on. Currently using Postgres which doesn't seem to have support for `PIVOT` so I couldn't test it properly either. But thanks for taking the time to write this example!

Comment: ok. I'll try to write a better way for you.